# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

While inside the show action I'm trying to link to the album controller's edit action but I keep getting an ActiveRecord Error saying: Couldn't find Album with 'id'=:id [WHERE "albums"."user_id" = ?]

Album controller:

```
def edit
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    if @album.update(album_params)
        redirect_to '/albums/:id'
    else
        render '/albums/edit'
    end
end

def show
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @album.photos
    @interests = current_user.interests
end
```

View:

```
    <% if @album.description.nil? %>
        <div class="description" id="new"><%= link_to 'Add Description', "/albums/:id/edit", :style => "text-decoration:none;" %></div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="description"><%= @album.description %></div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the edit path `edit_album_path` for the `@album`:

```
<% if @album.description.nil? %>
    <div class="description" id="new"><%= link_to 'Add Description', edit_album_path(@album), :style => "text-decoration:none;" %></div>
<% else %>
    <div class="description"><%= @album.description %></div>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you have defined the route for album edit path in `routes.rb` or you can simply have the album resource in `routes.rb` as follows which would create the paths that are needed for you to build the CRUD actions:

```
resources :albums
```

You can check your routes using the command `rake routes | grep album` in the your application path.